# AdSense adLayout parameter not working

Tags: ios, adsense

I'm using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.8.1) to load some ads like this:

```
let bannerView = GADSearchBannerView(adSize:kGADAdSizeFluid)
bannerView.adUnitID = "pub-Super-Secret"
bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(self.advertismentContainer.bounds),0)
bannerView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth
bannerView.delegate = self
bannerView.adSizeDelegate = self
self.advertismentContainer.addSubview(bannerView)

let request = GADDynamicHeightSearchRequest()
request.query = searchTerm
request.numberOfAds = 3
request.adTestEnabled = true
request.clickToCallExtensionEnabled = true

request.setAdvancedOptionValue("false", forKey:"domainLinkAboveDescription")
request.setAdvancedOptionValue("false", forKey:"sellerRatings")
request.setAdvancedOptionValue("false", forKey:"siteLinks")
request.setAdvancedOptionValue("sellerFirst", forKey:"adLayout")

bannerView.loadRequest(request)
```

I'm refering to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/s/docs/reference#page-level-parameter-descriptions) to find what parameters I can send. Sure enough, there is `adLayout` parameter, which is exactly what I need:

> By default, adLayout is disabled. If you wish to enable it, use this
>   line of code:
>
> ```
> 'adLayout' : 'sellerFirst'
> ```

Unfortunately, it comes with a star, but the star is never explained in the document I linked. I have tried to use the `sellerFirst` layout, but it doesn't work. Is it possible to use this parameter in the iOS SDK? The ads load fine but the `adLayout` parameter has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there are 2 problems:

- `adLayout` parameter needs to be enabled for the specific client-id, so if you want to use it you need to contact Google and ask them to enable it for you.
- at the moment, this parameter is only available for the web clients, I was told that on iOS and Android it's still work in progress.